# Upload file for primitive chat

Tags: android, ftp

I need a fast way to upload files to a ftp server.The files will be used for a primitive chat.Something like a timer and every 5 sec checks to see if the file x was added,if it was added open it and show it.

So please tell me an easy way to upload a file,because from google,I got only hundreds of lines of code.And yes,I need it for a FTP server.

Also it would be awesome to tell me a way to acces a file trough ftp open it and show it.(don't really need to download).

Comment: FTP is a horrible way to do a chat. At least build some Web Services and a small database to handle messages server side. Its simple to do and will make the app work a million times better.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient library - it's free and implements fairly easily with Android.  You can find a pretty easy how-to at the bottom of this blog post:
http://hoang17.com/posts/android/android-how-to-upload-a-file-via-ftp

That article should be especially helpful as it shows you how to store a string as data in a specific filename.

To be honest though - FTP seems like the absolute worst way to create any form of chat communication.  :)

Cheers.